# C# Local, Autos windows not showing DateTime as a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The locals and auto window are displaying DateTime variables as simply:

"{System.DateTime}"

How do I make the locals & auto windows show DateTime's as strings instead? (i.e. I want to see the .ToString() value, not the TypeName next to each variable name)

I may be going crazy but I think I used to see string values in the past, so maybe some system option got toggled accidentally and changed the behavior.

I am using VS 2012.

Comment: well after logging off and on this situation cleared up  -  so somehow the setting got changed during a session but not saved as a permanent setting - so not a big deal - but if anyone knows how to fix this without exiting VS I guess that would be useful to know